# Need to add weeks, days and months in a date for a package subscription

Tags: php, datetime

I am currently working on a package manager for my current project and I need to add package subscription date and package expiry date.

I am using php function `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` i.e

```
$package_subscription_start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

now here is my requirement:
I need to have packages such as for 1 day, 2 days, 5 days, 1 week, 4 weeks, 12 weeks, 1 month, 6 months, 9 months, 1 year, 2 years, 5years and 10 years.

How is it possible for me to add these values and calculate the package expiry date for inserting into mysql, something like

```
$package_expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 1 day;
$package_expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 5 days;
$package_expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 1 week;
$package_expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 4 weeks;
$package_expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 2 months;

$package_expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 2 years;
```

Lastly I need to take care of other date issues like valid date and leap year etc.
Also I need this to be done at php level, not using mysql / sql query.

I will appreciate any help in this direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) command in php?

```
echo $expires = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." + 1 day");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expires);
```

Gives you the output of

```
135082420020
12-10-21 08:56:40
```

Comment: You don't need to format the starting date in the call to `strtotime`; if it's the current date, you can just leave it out: `$expires = strtotime('+ 1 day')`.  Of course, at that point you can remove the intermediate variable entirely and get @fortune's answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was aware of that, was just trying to give OP an answer that included part of his own code to make it easier for him to understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 days'));
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 week'));
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+4 weeks'));
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 months'));
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 years'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the php [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

Eg to add time on to a date:

```
//Get the current date
$date = new DateTime();

//Add 1 day
$date->modify('+1 Day');

//Output in Y-m-d format
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

It has lots of other useful functions

Comment: Thnks wayneC for sparing your time for answering to my question. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d");// current da

    $date1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date1);
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date1);

    $date2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date2);

    $date3 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date3);

    $date4 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date4);

    $date5 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 year");
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date5);
?>
```